# Turn off Background Mode with swift code

Tags: ios, swift, background

I want to add a toggle in my application settings screen that allows the user to turn off background mode for my application. I build it with this enabled and I don't see another way to turn it off outside of the settings menu. Am I missing something?

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you create a Boolean and save it in `NSUserDefaults` depending on the toggle input and you could write a logic in `AppDelegate`

```
func application(application: UIApplication, performFetchWithCompletionHandler completionHandler: (UIBackgroundFetchResult) -> Void) {
    if NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().boolForKey("AllowBackgroundFetch"){
        func yourcode()
        completionHandler(.NewData)
    }else{
        print("user denied access")
    }
}
```